# Is there a way to return a set of objects combined as one object?

Tags: java

So I have a list of objects, these objects are intervals, for ex [2-10]. The left end is always less than the right end, (start < end).

Now say I calculate the union of intervals, 
like [2-9] and [10-12], **I want to return [2-9,10-12] as a single object**.

Is there any way to return that instance of intervals with just using a list of interval objects?

Also, the non number characters are built from my toString method, not be be confused as part of the object itself.

Comment: Why not return the different `IntervalUnion` objects in a data structure such as an `Array` or `ArrayList`?

Comment: You mean like return `List<IntervalUnion>`?

Comment: I can only return an object, and I am just wondering how to take the 2 objects [2-9] and [10-12], and combine them to return as [2-9,10-12]. This resulting new object would later be used as an instance of my class, this. for calculating the union in conjunction with other objects

Comment: But List is an object as well.

Comment: If you're talking about combining the (integer) intervals [2, 9] and [10, 12] then isn't the result the interval [2, 12]?

Comment: isn't an ArrayList an object ?

Comment: *I want to return [2-9,10-12] as a single object.* Then return a string if it must be in that form (as it is String we are talking here). You are making your life harder on your own only demand.

Comment: I need to compute the union of the object this (passed from the tester) and other. It should solely return the result as an IntervalUnion object.

Comment: @Antoniossss I have to use a toString method, right now my toString method only works for when the resulting union is a single interval. How can i accommodate for multiple intervals?

Comment: @javaWorld then you have to change the IntervalUnion class to include a list of ranges.

Comment: @javaWorld dude, if you make toString to print interval like `x-y` then ArrayList#toString will give you [el1.toString(),el2.toString()...] resulting in what you want

Answer (score 1):

Once you will get the `List` of your `IntervalUnion`s, you will be able to print it as required using already implemented `toString` method. Printing list will be like

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<MyInterval> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    myList.add(new MyInterval(5, 10));
    myList.add(new MyInterval(20, 30));
    System.out.println(myList.toString());
}

static class MyInterval {
    int x, y;
    MyInterval(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + "-" + y;
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
[5-10, 20-30]
```

So that is **exactly** as required. Now swap `MyInterval` with *collection* of combined interval unions and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a new structure for your IntervalUnion class that can handle multiple start and end points.

**WARNINGS: This unions implementation is not correct.  This implementation empties the two intervals you are union.  If [1,4] and [2,6] is unioned you will not get the expected result [1,6]**

```
public class Interval {

    List<Integer> starts = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> ends = new ArrayList<>();

    public Interval() {
    }

    public Interval(int start, int end) {
        starts.add(start);
        ends.add(end);
    }

    public Interval union(Interval interval) {
        Interval result = new Interval();
        while(this.starts.size()>0||interval.starts.size()>0){
            if(!this.starts.isEmpty() && this.starts.get(0) <= interval.starts.get(0)) {
                result.starts.add(this.starts.get(0));
                result.ends.add(this.ends.get(0));
                this.starts.remove(0);
                this.ends.remove(0);
            } else {
                result.starts.add(interval.starts.get(0));
                result.ends.add(interval.ends.get(0));
                interval.starts.remove(0);
                interval.ends.remove(0);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        for(int i = 0; i < starts.size();i++){
            sb.append(starts.get(i));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(ends.get(i));
            if(i<starts.size()-1) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Interval i = new Interval(1, 2);
        Interval j = new Interval(4, 5);
        Interval k = new Interval(7, 9);

        System.out.println(i.union(j).union(k));
    }
}
```

With output:
    [1-2,4-5,7-9]